# How to check if a variable is of a certian class (considering PHP 5.3 namespace too)

Tags: php, oop, class

How can I validate if an object is of a certian class? I currently use

```
get_class($obj) == 'User';
```

But it may look like `\KM\User` when I am elsewhere? I think this way maybe abit prone to developer error. Is there something like:

```
compare_class($obj1, User);
// or maybe
classof($obj) == User;
```

Comment: @Cold Hawaiian, now when I posted the question, but I tried that after you asked and yes I got "`KM\User`"

Answer (score 1):

Use the [instanceof](http://www.php.net/instanceof) operator:

```
if($foo instanceof User) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: ahh, I thought there must be something like that. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just

```
if ($obj instanceof User) {
  // $obj is of User or any descendant
}
```

should do it. This is affected by the 5.3 namespace handling, which means: If you are in `my\namespace`, it assume `User` to be `\my\namespace\User`. Or if you have something like `use another\namespace\User` it will be treated as exactly that class specified by the `use`-statement.